# Are pointers passed by value in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-value

Consider the following function definitions:

```cpp
int foo(int a);
int bar(int *b);

int main()
{
    int *ptr = new int(1);
    foo(*ptr);
    bar(ptr);
}
```

I need help clearing a few confusions I have.

1. When the control is inside `foo()`, is `a == *ptr && a == 1`?
2. When the control is inside `bar()`, is `b == ptr`?
3. When the control is inside `bar()`, is `&b == &ptr`?
4. If your answer to Q.3 was false then is there even anything as a call-by-reference in C++? It looks like the pointers were passed by value still but we have the contents (memory address to `new int(1)`) of `ptr` stored in another variable now. Is this because in this case the ptr was copied and it was as if we had the case in Q.1 but the integer value happens to be a memory address?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. When the control is inside `foo()`, is `a == *ptr && a == 1`?

Yes. The parameter `a` is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the argument `*ptr`, its value would be same as `*ptr`, i.e. `1`.

> 2. When the control is inside `bar()`, is `b == ptr`?

Yes. The parameter `b` is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the argument `ptr`, its value would be same as `ptr`.

> 3. When the control is inside `bar()`, is `&b == &ptr`?

No. They're independent objects and have different address.

> 4. If your answer to Q.3 was false then is there even anything as a call-by-reference in C++?

Yes. You can change it to pass-by-reference.

```
int bar(int *&b);
```

Then the parameter `b` would bind to the argument `ptr`, it's an alias of `ptr`; then `&b == &ptr` is true.

At last,

> Are pointers passed by value in C++?

Yes, they're passed by value themselves. The logic is the same as `foo` as you noticed.

#### EDIT

> Would you comment on whether `class_name* &b` is useful in any scenario?

Just as other non-pointer types being passed by reference, it's useful if you want to modify the pointer itself (not the pointee) in the function. e.g.

```
int bar(int *&b) {
    b = ...;  // make b pointing to anything else
              // the orginal pointer argument being passed gets changed too
}
```

Comment: it is also true that `&*b == &*ptr`, which is a form of pass-by-reference

Comment: Would you comment on whether `class_name* &b` is useful in any scenario?

Comment: @TwaritWaikar Answer revised.

Answer (score 10):

Unless you use the reference specifier `&` everything is passed by value.

In the case of `bar` the value of the variable `ptr` itself is copied into the local argument variable `b`. As such changes to `b` (like `b = some_other_pointer`) is local to the `bar` function only, the variable `ptr` will not be changed.

---

You can use pointers to *emulate* pass by reference, and this is commonly used in C.

For example inside `bar` if we did `*b = 5;` that would change the value of `*ptr`.